# How to bridge Wi-Fi Reciver and ADSL Modem so that I even can share the net connection with the WiFI device and second router?

Tags: router, internet, modem, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I have an ADSL modem which has an active internet connection. Then I have Wi-Fi Receiver/Emitter and another ADSL Modem.

```
 A: 1st ADSL Modem with active internet connection 
 B: Wifi Modem[Receiving wifi signals form A] 
 C: 2nd ADSL Modem [Connected to Wifi modem and then to a computer]

A:NSN Residential Router 1600
B:TP-LINK WA500G 
C:Teracom TDSL300W2
```

The first ADSL Modem(A) is a hotspot with its own internet connection. I am receiving it in Wi-Fi Modem(B), then second ADSL modem is connected to that Wifi Receiver and am able to connect to the Internet.

The both B and C are connected together and the C modem is connected to my computer, and the internet is working fine, which is receiving from router A who's sharing it via Wifi.

I want to share that internet connection with Wi-fi Access point from the Wi-fi modem B and router C.

[image]

Comment: It's because the LAN wire is short and I have connected B (Wi-Fi Reciever) to C (2nd ADSL Router) and also that I want to share Wi-Fi having internet access both from B and C.

Comment: C LAN is already connected to B LAN port. The Wan port well, its C has only a DSL line in it.  

What i have currently achieved is that I'm able to route A's internet connect - from B to C. 

What i want to achieve is- I want to access that internet connection from B's AP and also from C's AP.

I am sometimes able to access internet from C's AP though which is connected to my computer.

Comment: As you asked i have made a diagram, you can view it with the following link.

http://www.ashishdungdung.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Diagram.png

No C Doesn't have a active DSL line in it.

Yes AP on C is working, but some times only. 

B is connected to A via Wi-Fi. 

**Goal**: To be able to access the internet connection from B's AP and also C's AP.

Comment: The image link is accessible now, sorry for the trouble. Yes i edited the model of each router. And also yes, I want to use B's wifi radio both for extending the network, and serving the clients.

Comment: Did you make sure that DHCP is turned off on B and C?

Comment: Yes I did make sure that DHCP is off in both B and C! 

Current scenerio is that am able to access internet from C's AP (sometimes). But not able to access internet from B's AP.

Comment: Do you get an IP when connected to C (when not working) and B?  If so. can you ping the gateway.

Comment: Yes, I can access all the connected devices dashboard. I am able to ping them.

Comment: Ok, if you can access always ping and access A, and you get an IP from A, then I expect DNS is the problem.  Where is your DNS coming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23564/discussion-between-ashish-and-paul).